# Density of $C^\infty_0$ in a certain weighted $L^2$ space on the line

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $I$ be a (possibly unbounded) open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $r \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(I)$ with $r > 0$ and $r^{-1} \in L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(I)$.

> I would like to determine whether $C^\infty_0(I)$ is dense in the weighted $L^2$ space $L^2(I, r(x)dx)$, where $dx$ denotes standard Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my attempt so far. I simply try to leverage the fact that $C^\infty_0(I)$ is dense in the standard Lebesgue space $L^2(I,dx)$.

If $f \in L^2(I,rdx)$, then $f r^{1/2} \in L^2(I,dx)$, hence for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(I)$ so that 
$$ \|\varphi - fr^{1/2} \|_{L^2(I,dx)}< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. $$

So then for any $\psi \in C_0^\infty(I)$,
$$ \|\psi - f \|_{L^2(I,rdx)} \le \| \psi - \varphi r^{-1/2} \|_{L^2(I,rdx)} +  \|\varphi - fr^{1/2} \|_{L^2(I,dx)}< \| \psi - \varphi r^{-1/2} \|_{L^2(I,rdx)} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. $$

But now I can't seem to find a suitable way to choose $\psi$ so that I may control the term  $\| \psi - \varphi r^{-1/2} \|_{L^2(I,rdx)} = \|r\psi - \varphi\|_{L^2(I,dx)}$.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe $C^\infty_0(I)$ is dense in $L^p(I,\mu)$ for any locally finite measure $\mu$ on $I$ and any $1 \le p < \infty$.  I think this might be in Folland's *Real Analysis* and probably many other books.

Comment: Indeed, Folland's Proposition 7.9 shows that $C_0(I)$ is dense in $L^p(I,\mu)$.  And by mollification or Stone-Weierstrass, for any $f \in C_0(I)$ you can find a sequence $f_n \in C^\infty_0(I)$, all supported in a common compact subset of $I$, converging uniformly to $f$.  They therefore converge to $f$ in $L^p(I,\mu)$, and so you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Take $a$ such that $\|f-f_a\|_{L^2(I,r)}$ is small, where $f_a(x)=f(x)1_{|f(x)\le a|}1_{x\in [-a,a]}$ is bounded compactly supported
- Take $b$ such that $a\|r-r 1_{r(x)\le b^2}\|_{L^1[-a,a]}$ is small.
- Take $\epsilon$ such that $ a \|r\|_{L^1(\pm [a,a+\epsilon])}$ is small
- Take $\phi\in C^\infty_c[-a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon] ,|\phi(x)|\le a$ such that $b\|\phi-f_a\|_{L^2[-a,a]}$ is small

Thus
$$\|\phi 1_{[-a,a]}-f_a\|_{L^2(I,r1_{r(x)\le b^2})}\le b\|\phi-f_a\|_{L^2[-a,a]}$$

- $\|\phi (1-1_{x\in [-a,a]})\|_{L^2(r,I)} \le  a \|r\|_{L^1(\pm [a,a+\epsilon])}$

Then
$$\|\phi-f\|_{L^2(I,r)}\le \|\phi -f_a\|_{L^2(I,r)}+\|f-f_a\|_{L^2(I,r)}$$

$$\|\phi-f_a\|_{L^2(I,r)}\le \|\phi 1_{[-a,a]}-f_a\|_{L^2(I,r1_{r(x)\le b^2})}+2a\|r-r 1_{r(x)\le b^2}\|_{L^1[-a,a]}+\|\phi (1-1_{x\in [-a,a]})\|_{L^2(r,I)}$$